# Change a property with condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The query shall check wether a relation is already existing and in that case should check if a property has a special value and change it depending on the check. If that relation doesn exist it shall be created.

I have tried several ways and what comes closest is

```
MERGE (u:User {uuid: {userUUID}}) -[r:relation {rType: {rType}}]-> (n:Node)
ON CREATE SET 
    r.uuid = {relUUID},
    r.status = {relStatus}
ON MATCH SET
    r.status = {relStatus}
    WHERE r.status = "1"   // Only if r.status of the existing pattern is 1 it shall be changed to the value of relStatus
RETURN r
```

The WHERE isnt correct syntax - maybe someone has a hint how I can check a property and only change the property based on a special trigger when using ON MATCH.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify. In your sample query, do you want to test whether the value of `{relStatus_2}` is "1" before setting `status` to "1"?

Comment: True, I made a mistake. I have corrected the question. The check should be if r.status has the value 1. Typo, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MERGE (u:User {uuid: {userUUID}}) -[r:relation {rType: {rType}}]-> (n:Node)
ON CREATE SET 
    r.uuid = {relUUID},
    r.status = {relStatus}
ON MATCH SET
    r.status = CASE WHEN r.status = "1" THEN {relStatus} ELSE r.status END
RETURN r;
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a promising approach (learning complexer queries, thank you :)) Though I ran into an error: "A single relationship type must be specified for CREATE" - 'r' is set from my perspective so I am a bit lost with this error. Any hint is very appreciated.

Comment: Awesome, works! Found the error (was a missing declaration on other relationship). Thanks for boosting me to the next level :)